# Where does Bitrix generates logs?

Tags: bitrix

we are having some issues with the Outbound Webhook not getting invoked on Deal Update. Can someone advise how to enable log in Bitrix and check if there are any errors being thrown during Webhook call form Bitrix On-prem installation?

Comment: Does Bitrix not have any documentation of their own at all?

Comment: Product is really good, but documentation is just high level. Not even the architecture & deployment model is clear. Configuration options also not explained, just hoping someone from community could assist.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check in  'exception_handling' in file .settings.php

Example:

```php
'exception_handling' => array (
  'value' => array (
      'debug' => false, // disables error output to screen
       // ошибки для вывода в лог
      'handled_errors_types' => E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING,
      'exception_errors_types' => E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_COMPILE_WARNING,
      'ignore_silence' => true,
      'assertion_throws_exception' => true,
      'assertion_error_type' => 256,
      'log' => array (
          'settings' => array (
              'file' => "logs/bx_error/" . date("Y-m-d") . ".log",
              'log_size' => 1000000, // ~ 1Mb per file
          ),
      ),
  ),
  'readonly' => true,
),
```

2. You can log function to your hook.

Example:

```php
function writeToLog($data, $title = '') {
 $log = "\n------------------------\n";
 $log .= date("Y.m.d G:i:s") . "\n";
 $log .= (strlen($title) > 0 ? $title : 'DEBUG') . "\n";
 $log .= print_r($data, 1);
 $log .= "\n------------------------\n";
 file_put_contents(getcwd() . '/hook.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
 return true;
}
```

Document reference: https://helpdesk.bitrix24.com/open/5838415/